# Google-cast v3 custom namespace

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am now refactoring my sender application for Android using the new v3 Google Cast API.
The problem I encounter is when i add

```
List<String> namespaces = new ArrayList<>();
        namespaces.add("urn:x-cast:lalalalla");
...
return new CastOptions.Builder()
     .setSupportedNamespaces(namespaces)
```

the Android app does not display the chromecast icon anymore (I guess it does not discover chromecast devices anymore). 
What am I doing wrong with the namespace as without .setSupportedNamespaces it works fine as in the sample app?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show a complete version of the method that is building the CastOptions.

Comment: @AliNaddaf here it is:
CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
                .setImagePicker(new ImagePickerImpl())
                .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
.setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName()).build();
        return new CastOptions.Builder().setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.chromecast_receiver_id_stage)).setEnableReconnectionService(true).setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
                .build();

Answer (score 6):

This method can be a tad misleading sometimes. setSupportedNamespaces(ns) actually modifies the filter criteria for Cast devices for your app.

ie. it will only display Cast Devices currently running a receiver supporting the namespaces you specify. Unless this is what you want I'll advise to remove this call, you can still use custom namespaces when you're connected to your cast Device (after starting or joining a Cast Session)